# How can I make the size of a GUI in Ubuntu 20.04 larger?

Tags: graphics, fonts, gui, window

I am using an open-source software, dlclivegui, however, the GUI windows is very small.

I am not sure what setting in my Ubuntu 20.04 has made the Window so small since there is [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut-live/issues/23) from someone else who is also using the same command in Ubuntu but the sizing of GUI windows is normal.

[image]

P.S.: I previoulsy asked a similar question about MATLAB GUI size being so small but the solution doesn't really apply here. [Why are some GUI fonts so small in Ubuntu 20.04? How can I fix them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262836/why-are-some-gui-fonts-so-small-in-ubuntu-20-04-how-can-i-fix-them)